# how to do authorization against Owin authorization server from Client App (VS SPA template)

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a site setup with the SPA template, having a webapi and external providers configured.

What is the oauth flows I need to implement in the Authorization Server to support the case where I want to enable such users can login from my client application with any of the external providers to get a ExternalBearer token for my WebApi.

If anyone have some sample code that would be perfect.